# How to replace a get ladder with optional?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Class structure such as

```
 Class A {
     int val;
  }

 Class B {
   A a;
 }

 Class C {
   B b;
 }
```

Now, all the classes are from a third party service, from which I get a response and I want to read the int value.
But i dont want to do something like

lets assume c is a variable of type C.

```
if (c != null && c.getb != null) {
 B b = c.getb()
  and so on.
 }
```

I want to avoid these null checks as in reality these pojos are very hierarchical and have a lot of fields in them.

I tried using

```
Optional<Integer> val = Optional.ofNullable(c.getb().geta().getval());
val.elseThrow(Ex::new)
```

but this is not the right approach as (it throws null pointer exception if b is not present as optional is on int).
What can i do to tackle such a situation where i don't have control over the declarations of Pojos but want to avoid bull checks?

Comment: chain the `ofNullable()` instead?

Comment: Make a method in `C` that handles the whole thing. `Optional` doesn't make bad code go away, and get ladders are often a sign of naive class design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `map`

```
int val = Optional.ofNullable(c)
                  .map(x -> x.getb())
                  .map(x -> x.geta())
                  .map(x -> x.getval())
                  .getOrThrow(Ex::new);
```

You can use method references if you know the class name. e.g.

```
int val = Optional.ofNullable(c)
                  .map(C::getb)
                  .map(B::geta)
                  .map(A::getval)
                  .getOrThrow(Ex::new);
```

This works as `map` will call the function once if the value if it's not `null`, otherwise the result is also `null`. i.e. any null value falls through the chain of `map` calls to the end.

Comment: This approach worked. @Peter. Can you explain how does it work?

Comment: @CroskCool I added some explanation. Does that explain it?